# Clojure read object from a file and extract data

Tags: clojure

I am very new to closure so I am not fully sure how to do this. If I have a file `data.txt` with the following:

```
[
{:name "Steve"}
{:name "Issac"}
{:name "Lucas"}
{...}
]
```

I want to be able to read the contents of each `:name` tag and do something with the return value (in this case it will be printing to the console). I looked up online and found there is a method called `reader` and I understand how to open a file.

The Closure syntax confuses me slightly so I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should be 2 possiblities:

1) raw clojure by means clojure.core/read-string

```
(read-string  "['q 2 \"test\"]")
;; [(quote q) 2 "test"]
```

2) via clojure.edn/read-string

```
(clojure.edn/read-string "['q 2 \"test\"]")
;; ['q 2 "test"]
```

the 2nd one should be faster and safer (but does not eval and stuff),
but is only for [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) format (this is a subset of clojure code)

---

the string dummy (i.e from your data.txt)

```
;; a string, just for demo
(def s "[{:name \"Steve\" email: \"foo@bar.com\" }
         {:name \"Issac\"}
         {:name \"Lucas\"}]")
```

the rest is plain clojure, if you have trouble with clojure maps [here](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Maps%20%28IPersistentMap%29) is the doc

```
(doseq [name (map :name (clojure.edn/read-string s))]
  (println name))
;; Steve
;; Issac
;; Lucas
;; nil
```

Comment: I don't understand how to apply it to my answer? once the string is read, how do you retrieve the `:email` values

Comment: @Tom: updated a bit, but if your question is how to get `:email` out of `{:email ...}` you should really read a clojure beginner tutorial (i.e. [this](http://www.braveclojure.com/) one)

Comment: Thank you. All though an error is thrown when i try to read the emil section `invalid constituent character: @` so ill look into that.